# Shifting array within loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array and I want to shift it *n* times and return a new array of the shifted arrays.

As in [1,2,3,4] turns into

```
[[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
[ 2, 3, 4, 1 ],
[ 3, 4, 1, 2 ],
[ 4, 1, 2, 3 ],
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
[ 2, 3, 4, 1 ],
...
```

Using

```
function dataShift(len, inp){
var row = inp;
var rows = [];
for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
    row.push(row.shift());
    rows.push(row);
    console.log(rows[i]);
}
return rows;
}

console.log(dataShift(5,[1,2,3,4]));
```

`console.log(rows[i])` will print the desired result, however `console.log(dataShift(5,[1,2,3,4]))` only contain the last permutation of the original array `len` times.

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: You have to create a new array, not always append the same one.

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't do what you expect, it just takes elements of array and puts them in another array, no permutations executed.

Comment: `rows.push(row.slice());`

Comment: I got it now. Using inp.slice(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function dataShift(len, inp){
var row = inp;
var rows = [];
for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
    row.push(row.shift());
    var new1 = row.slice(0,len);
    rows.push(new1);
}
return rows;
}

console.log(dataShift(5,[1,2,3,4]));
```

the line `var new1 = row.slice(0, len)` is where the magic is. `row.slice` creates a new array object.

Your previous approach (pushing directly) eventually produces an array of object references pointing to the same object. So when you modify the object, all references are updated.

Another approach if you don't want to use `slice()` is by using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row))`

Comment: Your code should be accompanied with a brief explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int [] leftSwap(int [] arr, int n) {
        int l = arr.length;
        int [] result = new int[l];
        int  m = 0 ;
        int criticalIndex = l - n ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i <result.length  ; i++) {
            if(i < criticalIndex) {
                result[i] = arr[n];
                n++;
            }

            else {

                result[i] = arr[m];
                        m++;
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```